# Android turning off bluetooth programmatically doesn’t work as expected

Tags: android, bluetooth

I’m working on Bluetooth communication between Silicon labs MCU + BLE113 and android app. I want to programmatically disable Bluetooth from android side. There are some examples online I found helpful. And my code is as follows:

```
private void showWifiSet() {
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new MaterialDialog.Builder(SendWifiBLEActivity.this)
                .content(R.string.wifi_set)
                .positiveText(android.R.string.ok)
                .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                        if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                            bluetoothAdapter.disable();
                        }
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }
});
```

}

Now my question is, when this code runs, Bluetooth is shown disabled on android phone, and BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF is caught. But I cannot get the ble_evt_connection_disconnected event on MCU, either the onConnectionStateChange in android. And my MCU still shows connected through Bluetooth with android phone. The way I found to disconnect MCU and android app is 1, close app, 2, stop debugging mode on android studio, or 3, manually disable Bluetooth in android phone system settings.

Can anybody help me with that please? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have set up the adapter correctly as well, like `BluetoothAdapter bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();`?

Comment: Yes. My code is : BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        bluetoothAdapter = (bluetoothManager != null) ? bluetoothManager.getAdapter() : null;